# Clear cart function and Json Webstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm currently working on a project for university where we are to create a website for a company that wants to sell products online. I have been going through some difficulty when it came to the shopping cart but fortunately I was able to get a functioning 'drag and drop' cart to work with the products on my site.

I am now stuck where I attempted to add a clear cart button that does exactly what it says 'clear the cart of all products' but I have had no luck. An addition to this I am struggling to find a good source that could help me with getting JSON storage to work with my cart.

These are the final things I have to get done. Any help or guides are appreciated.

This is the coding:

```js
var data = {"total":0,"rows":[]};
  var totalCost = 0;
  
  $(function(){
   $('#cartcontent').datagrid({
    singleSelect:true
   });
   $('.item').draggable({
    revert:true,
    proxy:'clone',
    onStartDrag:function(){
     $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
     $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
    },
    onStopDrag:function(){
     $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
    }
   });
   $('.cart').droppable({
    onDragEnter:function(e,source){
     $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
    },
    onDragLeave:function(e,source){
     $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
    },
    onDrop:function(e,source){
     var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
     var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
     addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
    }
   });
  });
  

 $("#clear_cart").click(function(event){
 clearCart();
 displayCart();
});
 
  function addProduct(name,price){
  
   function add(){
    for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
     var row = data.rows[i];
     if (row.name == name){
      row.quantity += 1;
      return;
     }
    }
    data.total += 1;
    data.rows.push({
     name:name,
     quantity:1,
     price:price
    });
   }
   add();
   totalCost += price;
   $('#cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data);
   $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $'+totalCost);   
  }
```

```css
.products{
   list-style:none;
   margin-right:150px;
   padding:0px;   
  }
  .products li{
   display:inline;
   float:left;
   margin:10px;
  }
  .item{
   display:block;
   text-decoration:none;
   background-color: #edeeef;
  }
  .item img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 135px;
  }
    
  .cart th
  {
   text-align: center;
  }
  .item p{

   font-weight:bold;
   text-align:center;
   color:#c3c3c3;
  }
  .cart{
   position:absolute;
   right: 0;
   bottom:0;
   width:auto;
   height:60%;
   background:#ccc;
   padding:0px 10px;
   margin: auto;
  }
  .cart h1{
   text-align:center;
   color:#555;
   font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  .cart img{
   padding: 10px;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
  }
  
  h2{
   position:absolute;
   font-size:20px;
   left:10px;
   bottom:20px;
   color:#555;
  }
  .total{
   margin:0;
   text-align:right;
   padding-right:20px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>


<article>
 <h5>Men's Bikes</h5>
 <ul class = "products">
  <li>
   <a href = '#' class="item">
    <img src ="Bikes\1.jpg"/>
    <div>
     <p>Stellar</p>
     <p>Price:$1245</p>
    </div>
   </a>   
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href = '#' class="item">
    <img src ="Bikes\41.jpg"/>
    <div>
     <p>Hazdorn</p>
     <p>Price:$1100</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href = '#' class="item">
    <img src ="Bikes\20.jpg"/>
    <div>
     <p>Drover</p>
     <p>Price:$870</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href = '#' class="item">
    <img src ="Bikes\6.jpg"/>
    <div>
     <p>Blizzard</p>
     <p>Price:$1780</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
      </ul>
</article>

<div class="cart">
 <img src="Pictures/basket.png" class="basket"/>
 <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
 <div style="background:#fff">
 <table id="cartcontent" fitColumns="true" style="width:200px;height:auto;">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th field="name" width=200>Name</th>
    <th field="quantity" width=150 align="right">Quantity</th>
    <th field="price" width=100 align="right">Price</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
 </div>
 <p class="total">Total: $0</p>
 <p><input type="button" class="clearbutton" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()"></p>
 <h2>Drop here to add to cart</h2>
</div>
```

P.S. this is my first year studying anything to do with coding.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are using the `data` object as your shopping cart.  To clear it, all you need to do is reset the object.

```
data.total = 0
data.rows = []
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, so the code should look something like this:
 $("#clear_cart").click(function(event){
 data.total = 0
 data.rows = []
});

And if so I'm now getting an error that tells me 'clear_cart' is not defined under my html code where I have:
  <p><input type="button" class="clearbutton" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()"/></p>

Comment: $("#clear_cart") is looking for a button in your html that has id="clear_cart"      Also on a side note, I would recommend learning just with Javascript at first, not jumping into jQuery.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I found a way round that by rewriting it as:  function clear_cart(){
 data.total = 0
 data.rows = []
 };

Comment: That gets rid of the error but sadly the clear cart button isnt doing anything when I click it :/ as I stated I'm pretty nooby with all this but I haven't got much time to go back to learn from scratch, I've got myself familiar with most stuff on here but I still find it difficult

Comment: Hang on, the button actually works! Only issue is the list isnt updating when I press the clear cart button, so my items seem to still be there until I drag another item to the cart where it'll refresh and start from an empty cart with just the item you have just dragged. But the total cost isnt starting from 0 again, it just keeps adding up the total costs

Comment: Yep, just refresh the cart the same way you do when you add an item

Comment: Majority of this JS code I found online but I was able to edit it to fit my code so I'm struggling to find the bit you are talking about, maybe you could paste which part of code does that?

Comment: Then you won't learn anything! :)  Just go through what happens when you add items, and find where the html code is updated for the new data